# account name in PyGithub

Tags: python, github, pygithub

I am using the package PyGithub in order to try and automate the creation of a new github repo.

```
from github import Github

g = Github(token)
user = g.get_user()
repo = user.create_repo(name)
```

After creating that repo I am creating a local one too, and simply try link them.

One of the commands I need to execute is `git remote add origin git@github.com:<AccountName>/<RepoName>.git`

I don't want to hard-code my account name into this script so I am trying to get that name from the `Github` package.
Apparently, on github, I have two 'user names' - one of them is the profile name and the other one is the account name.
When I execute `user.name` I get my profile name and not my account name which I need.

Is there anyway to get that account name specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking around in the [documentation](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) I found that you can get the [`login`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/MainClass.html#get-current-user) name  like this:

```
from github import Github

g = Github(token)
user = g.get_user()

print(user.login)
#OUTPUT: my_username
```